# Rim hook decomposition and volume of moduli spaces

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, moduli-spaces, recurrences

I did some computer experiments, counting the number of rim-hook decompositions (aka border-strip decompositions) of rectangles of shape $2n \times n$, where each strip has size $n$.

Here are 12 of the 1379 such decompositions for $n=4$:
[image: 12 border strip decompositions]

Let $a_n$ be the number of such decompositions.
I conjecture that $a_n$ is given by [A115047](https://oeis.org/A115047) in OEIS,
that is, $a(0)=1$ and
$$
a(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n
   \binom{n - 1}{i - 1} \binom{n + 3}{i + 1} a(i - 1) a(n - i) \frac{ i(n - i + 1)}{2 (n + 2)},
$$
or $1, 5, 61, 1379, 49946, 2648967,...$. 
Edit(2018-02-22): My student have checked that the sequences agree up to $n=12$, which is quite compelling.

The interesting part is that there is no such reference in OEIS. This entry regards *Weil-Petersson volumes of muduli spaces of an $n$-punctured Riemann sphere*, which is quite far from my field.

Q: *Can we prove the recursion above?*

I think this (conjectured) connection is interesting, giving a combinatorial interpretation of moduli space volumes. 
Perhaps this can be extended to other genus?

*EDIT:* Using the strategy in the formula given in the answer below,
this conjecture is now proved in [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.09778).

*Edit II* [Paper is now published in the Journal of Integer sequences.](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL22/Alexandersson/alex4.pdf)
The answer to the original question is therefore, YES.

Comment: It should be noted that counting "rim-hook tableaux" is much easier - there is a hook-formula for that.

Comment: Love this question, as I have connections to both sides -- I'm busy the rest of this week, but hopefully will get to think about this this weekend, though...But in the meantime, a quick question about counting the tableaux side -- it's *much* easier to do if we number the parts of the decomposition like a tableaux, sure -- but some of these decompositions have more than one numbering.  Curious how you deal with that, e.g., a(2)=5, instead of 6=4!/2^2, a(3)=61 instead of 90=6!/2^3....

Comment: @PaulJohnson: Right, I spoke a bit with Igor Pak on this (he has some stuff on this type of decompositions), and not surprisingly, the labeled objects are much easier. Note that the number of ways to tile a $n\times n$-square with $n$-strips is simply $n!$.

Comment: Not really relevant, but if we remove the condition that each strip has size $n$ then the number of ways is $(F_2 F_4\cdots F_{2n})^2F_{2n+1}^n$, where $F_m$ denotes a Fibonacci number. See *Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol. 2, Exercise 7.66.

Comment: Very nice question! Did you do any experiments counting the number of rim-hook decompositions of $2n\times n$ rectangles where each strip has size $k$ for some $k\mid 2n^2$?

Comment: @TimothyChow: That's interesting! No, I have not tried that as the choice of $k$ is not canonical. Not every pair of $(n,k)$ allows a solution, so I imagine there'll be primes and stuff (which I try to stay away from).

Comment: Hmm. Some half-baked reductions (the lower left and upper right triangular corners are determined uniquely by the remaining parallelogram; some more...) give me some hope I may be able to push your calculations past n=5 at some point; not going to be able to give a serious try for quite a while, though.

An obstruction for proving the recurrence: the combinatorial factors sometimes have a two on a denominator, and so we depend on the i, n+1-i symmetry to get integers.  But my instincts to look for a geometric/Catalan-y approach to decomposing the picture break this symmetry...

Comment: Also, looking at it from the other side (moduli spaces) there's a hope that we write that side in terms of the combinatorics of trees (since it's a genus 0 volume), and maybe that formulation would give us a handhold.

Comment: I designed a quite efficient algorithm, and managed to test up to n=7. Unless you design an algorithm where you don't go through all solutions, it does not seem possible to go higher than 8, because it just grows too fast. Anyway, I think n=7 is enough for an empirical proof, the only way you can improve this is by giving a complete proof for arbitrary n.

Comment: @oak I have a student now working on related problems, and he did the same computation as well a few days ago (with bruteforce enumeration).
Perhaps we'll try to attack the problem somehow, but the coefficients in the recursion seem unintuitive. One would like a 'bijective' attack on this I suppose, so interpreting these coefficients is essential.

Comment: Fascinating! Is there some interesting numerology in the $n\times n$ case as well? I imagine I could write some code but figured it wouldn't hurt to ask...

Comment: @user61318: Sure, is is quite easy to figure out a bijection with $S_n$, that is, permutations of n letters. I have a bachelor student working on some other cases, the $n\times (n+1)$ case is fairly fun.

Comment: One nice story would be if there were a decomposition of the moduli space into volume-one regions, in bijection with your tableaux. Devadoss has a number of papers like this http://satyandevadoss.org/papers/ . If that were true, then there should be a theory of glue tableaux serving as the codim 1 strata bordering two regions. This is one way set-valued tableaux naturally arise, as in http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/0502.5144 .

Comment: @AllenKnutson: Yes that would be very interesting! There is a notion of 'flips', in some sense, local moves that makes a connected graph out of border-strip decompositions. I. Pak has some stuff on this - perhaps such flips (or similar) is what would represent such boundaries between regions.

For example, in the nxn-case, it is fairly easy to define flips such that one obtains a structure isomorphic to the weak order on permutations.

Comment: Theorem 34 in the preprint has two mistakes - you say the Weil-Peterson volume of the $n$-punctured Riemann sphere instead of the Weil-Peterson volume of the moduli space of $n$-punctured Riemann spheres, and you write $v_{n-3}$ instead of $v_n$.

Comment: @AllenKnutson the last link in your [last comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/292312/rim-hook-decomposition-and-volume-of-moduli-spaces#comment729251_292312) is broken, the working one is https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0502144

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Abacus is quite useful to count objects related to hooks. For partition $((2n)^n)$, the $n$-abacus is $\{2n, \dots, 3n-1\}$ on $n$ runners. Thus, the number of labelled rim hook decompositions (labelled by the order of removal) equals to the number of permutations of $x_1, \dots, x_n, y_1, \dots, y_n$ such that $x_i$ appears before $y_i$ for every $i$.

In order to count unlabelled rim hook decompositions, we need to find out when the order of two consecutive rim hook removal can be swapped. Then, we can add some constraint that allows one type of removal, but forbids the other type of removal. All labelled rim hook decompositions with the new constraint are in bijection with unlabelled rim hook decompositions.

If we translate the new constraint we get to permutations of $x_i$'s and $y_i$'s, that means: the permutation does not have consecutive $x_i$ and $y_j$ such that $i \gt j$.

It is then straightforward to use inclusion-exclusion to count the number of permutations satisfying both requirements. I get a complicated formula for $a_n$, and the formula matches A115047 for $n$ up to $60$. I believe that it should not be too hard to prove that the formula for $a_n$ satisfies the recursion.

---

Edit (Mar. 3, 2018)

The $n$-abacus of a partition $\lambda = (\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_m)$ consists of $n$ runners and $m$ beeds located at $\{\lambda_i + m - i\}$, and the map from beeds to runners is given by $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} / n \mathbb{N}$. Removing an $n$-hook corresponds to the move of a beed along its runner to a smaller adjacent unoccupied location. A labelled rim hook decomposition is just a sequence of such moves so that no further moves can be made.

For the partition $((2n)^n)$, let $x_i$ be the move of the beed at $2 n + i - 1$ to $n + i - 1$, and let $y_i$ be the move of the beed at $n + i - 1$ to $i - 1$. Two hook removal at $b$ and $b'$ can be swapped if and only if $|b - b'| \gt n$. For this particular partition, that means $x_i y_j$ or $y_j x_i$ such that $i \gt j$. Therefore, we can reformulate the problem of finding $a_n$ to a problem of counting permutations of $x_i$'s and $y_i$'s. For general partitions, the same method works, and we just need to consider possibly larger "alphabet" and longer "forbidden words".

Below is one method of counting such permutations. There must be a much better way to count them.

Suppose that we know some consecutive occurrences of $x_i y_j$'s. Consider the bipartite graph with vertices $x_i$'s and $y_i$'s and edges $x_i y_i$ for all $i$ and $x_i y_j$ for all known consecutive $x_i y_j$ with $i \gt j$. This bipartite graph is a disjoint union of paths, otherwise it would not be legitimate. Let $p$ be the partition such that the parts of $2p$ are the sizes of the connected components of the bipartite graph mentioned above. Therefore, by inclusion-exclusion, we have the formula
$$ a_n = \sum_{p \vdash n} (-1)^{|p - 1|} \frac{1}{|m|!} {|m| \choose m} {|p| \choose p} {|p + 1| \choose p + 1},$$
where $p$ runs over partitions of $n$, $m := (m_1, \dots, m_n)$ with $m_i$ being the multiplicity of $i$ in $p$, $p + c$ is the addition of $c$ to each part of $p$, $|p|$ is the sum of parts in $p$ and ${|p| \choose p}$ is the multinomial coefficient.

Comment: Yes, it would be great if you could post your formula!